# How should I Pass Authentication Ids through to my database API from Node Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, express-session

I've created a basic project consisting of a webpage running on a basic node express service, a sequelize API and a postgreSQL dB.

The webpage has API requests, which I initially set up as pointing directly to the API. I believe this to be an incorrect approach and am therefore now going to route these back through my node express web service.

What I would like to do is have my express server act as a proxy for these requests through to my API. However, having added express-session and redis into my project so I can uniquely identify client requests, so would like to additionally pass a session_id (or db user_id) to the API during this redirecting process.

I have managed to do this by writing a function myself using axios, e.g:-

```
app.get('/venues/:town', async (req, res) => {

const sess = req.session;
console.log(sess.uniqueid);

let town = req.params.town;
let venueUrl = process.env.API_DEPLOYMENT_URL+"/venues/"+town;

const getVenueData = async () => {

    try {
        const venuesResp = await axios.get(venueUrl, {
            params: {
              SessionID: sess.uniqueid
            }});
    
        console.log('Venues via axios request');
        return venuesResp.data.venues;
    }
    catch (err){
        console.error(err);
        res.json({ err: {message: err.message } } )
    }
}

getVenueData().then(venues => res.json({ venues }) );
})
```

But I am wondering if there is a more suitable way of doing this? I'm guessing there must be some proxy package available to save me doing this for various requests?